# Open and layout multiple applications on Ubuntu desktop with a single command

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-11.04

Is it possible on Ubuntu to open, automatically size and layout multiple applications with a single command? Solution with no requirements of advanced system administration skills are gratefully appreciated, as I do not have the knowledge to do so.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "automatically size and layout"? Do you mean sizing the windows uniformly (e.g. 4 applications; each taking up 1/4th of the display)?

Comment: Not exactly. For example, when i decide to work on some project, i need to open browser, developer console, terminal, code editor etc. Then size and place all this windows on my displays in most comfort way (not exactly uniform). Different kind of project requires another set of apps. So i want to automate this tasks to be able to get necessary environment any time i need to work on particular project.

Answer (score 0):

I use something like the following function in my `~/.bashrc` file:

```
# doing this from memory, will fill in details when I can...
dev_project ()
{
  # ip/port of local machine for testing
  dev_url='192.168.1.1:8000'

  # change into the project's home directory
  cd projects/project

  # fire up an editor with a default file
  emacs todo.org &

  # a spare terminal for grepping etc.
  gnome-terminal &

  # open the browser
  chromium-browser http://$dev_url/ &

  # start the django dev server in this terminal and leave it running
  ./manage.py runserver $dev_url

  # echo out a command that can be cut & pasted to 
  # restart the django server after a ctrl-c
  echo "./manage.py runserver $dev_url"
}
```

Once this is defined, you can open a terminal and type `dev_project` and it will start everything up for you.

As for positioning the windows, there used to be compiz plugins that could do that, not sure what the gnome3/unity options are. You could also look into something like [wmctrl](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/).